# Is it possible to use Kibi with Elasticsearch 5.2?

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch

We are in the process of migrating our MSSQL database to an elasticsearch platform, and have run into the (apparently common) problem of many parents to one child relationship, when trying to access information from multiple tables.
It seems Kibi is capable of allowing these type of relationships to exist, however has only been optimized for ES 4.2. Has anyone found a way to use Kibi , as opposed to Kibana on the newest ES?

PS. changing the DB is not an option, as this is a proof of concept only.